# How to read a table in lua

Tags: lua, lua-api

I have a table as follows below.

```
Table = {
        1,      2,      3,
        6,      7,      8,
        11,     12,     13,...
}
```

I want to read that table and say how many values were read, the more I'm having trouble with my code below, always the following error occurs when reading PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API

I am using lua 5.2, the error is pointed out here

```
lua_getfield (L, -1, "Table");
```

can someone help me with this reading, I'm new in lua.

```
void read_table(void) {

    int var1;
    long double var2;
    lua_State *L;
    L = = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "table.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)) {
        printf("cannot run cofig file: %s\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        lua_getfield(L, -1, "Table");

        if (lua_type(L, -1) == 5) {
            var1 = 1;
            while (1)
            {
                lua_pushnumber(L, var2);
                lua_gettable(L, -2);

                if (!lua_isnumber(L, -1))
                break;
                lua_tonumber(L, -1);
                lua_settop(L, -2);
                ++var1;

                lua_close(L);
            }
            printf("table %d invalid\n", var1);
        }
        else {
            printf("table should be a table\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Reading %d numbers\n", var1);
}
```

Comment: What do you think is at stack index `-1` at the point where you call `lua_getfield(L, -1, "Table")`?

Comment: The lua_getfield was giving error, as I am using lua 5.2 I switched to `lua_getglobal (L, "Table");`

Comment: That's not a 5.2 thing but sure. Did that solve your problem?

Comment: reading is made, only 1 value is read, but should read all.

Comment: Where does `var2` get given a value? You are pushing an uninitialized value onto the lua stack.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble for that I'm using as a basis a debugging made by IDA, here's the link, I'm trying to write like is in debugging.  http://pastebin.com/kTbraLp4

Comment: First question, does "table.lua" actually return a table back when executed? Does that table contain a `Table` key as one of its field?

Comment: Why is `lua_close` in the inner most loop?

Comment: Use [`lua_rawgeti`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_rawgeti) if you're trying to iterate through the array part of the table. If you just want to count the elements in it and there are no 'holes' you can use [`lua_objlen`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_objlen).

Comment: I managed to read, now how can I see the values that are being read? Another thing how can I start making the count while from 0 and not 1 e.g       `for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)`